# Money Plant Leaves

Tags: plant-health

What can I do to make my money plant healthy? It's leaves are like burnt and also has holes in it. If I place it indoor, the leaves become yellow and fall off. Posting pics too.[image][image: This is the pic of entire plant]

Comment: Money plant is a common name usually used for Crassula ovata, sometimes  for Pachira aquatica, but your plant is neither of  those. It looks vaguely like Devil's Ivy (Epripremnum aureum) but can we have another photo from further away, showing the whole plant to try to ID what it actually is please

Comment: Hi Bamboo, I have added another pic of the plant , perhaps it can be identified now. Thanks

Comment: How long have you had this plant  and where are you in the world?

Comment: I have had it for around 20 years . I am in India.

Answer (score 2):

I think this plant is Epipremnum aureum, but its hard to be sure because its in such poor condition. There's a similar plant known as Heartleaf Philodendron, but fortunately, the care for both is similar.

If you've had your plant for 20 years, and its been in the same pot for some years, its time  to repot it, preferably cutting the rootball in half and potting up the two sections separately. Remove all badly damaged leaves at the same time, as well as inspecting closely for insect infestation. If you can, use new, sterile potting soil, but I am not sure you can get that where you live. Water thoroughly after this procedure, and allow the pots to drain freely prior to replacing into any outer tray. Ongoing, water when the surface of the soil in the pot feels just about dry to the touch, then water thoroughly, emptying out the tray or pot beneath after 30 minutes so its not left standing in water.

These plants do not like direct sunlight, preferring bright daylight instead. That obvious damage on the plant might be from sunlight,  or a combination of that and insufficient watering, possibly caused by the fact its likely rootbound. Usually grown indoors in bright light as houseplants, they can be placed outdoors, out of sunlight, in countries  where the temperatures are high enough. More info here https://www.proflowers.com/blog/pothos-plant-care

Comment: Thanks a ton. Will follow your advice. And yes we do get sterile potting soil here.